# Pagination new data Isn't added to the ListView.builder at the end instead refreshed replacing previous data

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an API from where I am get 10 data entries on each hit. What I want to do is to add these entries at the end of the ListView.builder List. At the moment it refreshes the ListView.builder instead of populating more entries.
Code for the whole screen is quite longer so I trimmed down only for one type of entry.

```
class PaginatedScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const PaginatedScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PaginatedScreen> createState() => _PaginatedScreenState();
}

class _PaginatedScreenState extends State<PaginatedScreen> {

  final scrollController = ScrollController();
  int offSetCurrent = 0;
  bool hasMore = true;
  bool isLoading = false;

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent == scrollController.offset) {
        setState(() {
          getDiscussion(offSetCurrent);
          print('initial offSet: $offSetCurrent');
          offSetCurrent = offSetCurrent + 10;
          print('new offset $offSetCurrent');
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose(){
    scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<PaginatedModel> getDiscussion(offSetCurrent) async {
    // if (isLoading) return;
    // isLoading = true;

    SharedPreferences sp = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var parameters = {
      'RangeFrom':offSetCurrent.toString(),
      'AccessToken':sp.getString('AccessToken'),
      'DiscussionID':'22848',
    };
    var urlfetch = Uri(
      scheme: "https",
      host: baseUrl,
      path: discussionAPIPath,
      queryParameters: parameters,
    );
    try {
      http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(urlfetch.toString()));
      var data = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
      var snapshot = PaginatedModel.fromJson(data);
      var itemsTotal = snapshot.courseLessonDetailsData!.first.discussionDetails!.first.discussionsMessages!.length;
      if (itemsTotal < 10){
        setState((){
          hasMore = false;
        });
      }
      print(data);
      print('Discussion API HIT with offset $offSetCurrent');
      // isLoading = false;

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {

        return PaginatedModel.fromJson(data);
      }
      else {
        print(response.statusCode);
        return PaginatedModel.fromJson(data);
      }
    }
    catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      rethrow;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
          future: getDiscussion(offSetCurrent),
          builder: (dCtx, dSnapshot){
            if (dSnapshot.hasData){
              var itemCount = dSnapshot.data!.courseLessonDetailsData!.first.discussionDetails!.first.discussionsMessages!.length;
              return ListView.builder(
                  controller: scrollController,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: itemCount + 1,
                  itemBuilder: (context, idx){
                    if (idx < itemCount){
                      return Column(
                          children: List<Widget>.generate(dSnapshot.data!.courseLessonDetailsData!.first.discussionDetails!.length, (i) => Container(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Html(data: dSnapshot.data!.courseLessonDetailsData!.first.discussionDetails!.first.discussionsMessages![idx].message.toString()),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ))
                      );
                    }
                    else {
                      return Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 32),
                        child: Center(
                          child: hasMore? CircularProgressIndicator() : Text('No More Data'),
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                  }
              );
            }
            else {
              return const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
          }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my Model:

```
class PaginatedModel {
  PaginatedModel({
      List<CourseLessonDetailsData>? courseLessonDetailsData,}){
    _courseLessonDetailsData = courseLessonDetailsData;
}

  PaginatedModel.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    if (json['CourseLessonDetailsData'] != null) {
      _courseLessonDetailsData = [];
      json['CourseLessonDetailsData'].forEach((v) {
        _courseLessonDetailsData?.add(CourseLessonDetailsData.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }
  List<CourseLessonDetailsData>? _courseLessonDetailsData;
PaginatedModel copyWith({  List<CourseLessonDetailsData>? courseLessonDetailsData,
}) => PaginatedModel(  courseLessonDetailsData: courseLessonDetailsData ?? _courseLessonDetailsData,
);
  List<CourseLessonDetailsData>? get courseLessonDetailsData => _courseLessonDetailsData;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final map = <String, dynamic>{};
    if (_courseLessonDetailsData != null) {
      map['CourseLessonDetailsData'] = _courseLessonDetailsData?.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return map;
  }

}

class CourseLessonDetailsData {
  CourseLessonDetailsData({
      String? requestStatus, 
      List<DiscussionDetails>? discussionDetails,}){
    _requestStatus = requestStatus;
    _discussionDetails = discussionDetails;
}

  CourseLessonDetailsData.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    _requestStatus = json['request_status'];
    if (json['DiscussionDetails'] != null) {
      _discussionDetails = [];
      json['DiscussionDetails'].forEach((v) {
        _discussionDetails?.add(DiscussionDetails.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }
  String? _requestStatus;
  List<DiscussionDetails>? _discussionDetails;
CourseLessonDetailsData copyWith({  String? requestStatus,
  List<DiscussionDetails>? discussionDetails,
}) => CourseLessonDetailsData(  requestStatus: requestStatus ?? _requestStatus,
  discussionDetails: discussionDetails ?? _discussionDetails,
);
  String? get requestStatus => _requestStatus;
  List<DiscussionDetails>? get discussionDetails => _discussionDetails;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final map = <String, dynamic>{};
    map['request_status'] = _requestStatus;
    if (_discussionDetails != null) {
      map['DiscussionDetails'] = _discussionDetails?.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return map;
  }

}


class DiscussionDetails {
  DiscussionDetails({
      List<DiscussionsMessages>? discussionsMessages,}){
    _discussionsMessages = discussionsMessages;
}

  DiscussionDetails.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    if (json['DiscussionsMessages'] != null) {
      _discussionsMessages = [];
      json['DiscussionsMessages'].forEach((v) {
        _discussionsMessages?.add(DiscussionsMessages.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }
  List<DiscussionsMessages>? _discussionsMessages;
DiscussionDetails copyWith({  List<DiscussionsMessages>? discussionsMessages,
}) => DiscussionDetails(  discussionsMessages: discussionsMessages ?? _discussionsMessages,
);
  List<DiscussionsMessages>? get discussionsMessages => _discussionsMessages;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final map = <String, dynamic>{};
    if (_discussionsMessages != null) {
      map['DiscussionsMessages'] = _discussionsMessages?.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return map;
  }

}


class DiscussionsMessages {
  DiscussionsMessages({
      String? messageID, 
      String? id, 
      String? studentName, 
      String? message, 
      String? replyMessage, 
      List<OtherStudentMessages>? otherStudentMessages,}){
    _messageID = messageID;
    _id = id;
    _studentName = studentName;
    _message = message;
    _replyMessage = replyMessage;
    _otherStudentMessages = otherStudentMessages;
}

  DiscussionsMessages.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    _messageID = json['MessageID'];
    _id = json['ID'];
    _studentName = json['StudentName'];
    _message = json['Message'];
    _replyMessage = json['ReplyMessage'];
    if (json['OtherStudentMessages'] != null) {
      _otherStudentMessages = [];
      json['OtherStudentMessages'].forEach((v) {
        _otherStudentMessages?.add(OtherStudentMessages.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }
  String? _messageID;
  String? _id;
  String? _studentName;
  String? _message;
  String? _replyMessage;
  List<OtherStudentMessages>? _otherStudentMessages;
DiscussionsMessages copyWith({  String? messageID,
  String? id,
  String? studentName,
  String? message,
  String? replyMessage,
  List<OtherStudentMessages>? otherStudentMessages,
}) => DiscussionsMessages(  messageID: messageID ?? _messageID,
  id: id ?? _id,
  studentName: studentName ?? _studentName,
  message: message ?? _message,
  replyMessage: replyMessage ?? _replyMessage,
  otherStudentMessages: otherStudentMessages ?? _otherStudentMessages,
);
  String? get messageID => _messageID;
  String? get id => _id;
  String? get studentName => _studentName;
  String? get message => _message;
  String? get replyMessage => _replyMessage;
  List<OtherStudentMessages>? get otherStudentMessages => _otherStudentMessages;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final map = <String, dynamic>{};
    map['MessageID'] = _messageID;
    map['ID'] = _id;
    map['StudentName'] = _studentName;
    map['Message'] = _message;
    map['ReplyMessage'] = _replyMessage;
    if (_otherStudentMessages != null) {
      map['OtherStudentMessages'] = _otherStudentMessages?.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return map;
  }

}


class OtherStudentMessages {
  OtherStudentMessages({
      String? replyID, 
      String? repliedBy, 
      String? replyMessage,}){
    _replyID = replyID;
    _repliedBy = repliedBy;
    _replyMessage = replyMessage;
}

  OtherStudentMessages.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    _replyID = json['ReplyID'];
    _repliedBy = json['RepliedBy'];
    _replyMessage = json['ReplyMessage'];
  }
  String? _replyID;
  String? _repliedBy;
  String? _replyMessage;
OtherStudentMessages copyWith({  String? replyID,
  String? repliedBy,
  String? replyMessage,
}) => OtherStudentMessages(  replyID: replyID ?? _replyID,
  repliedBy: repliedBy ?? _repliedBy,
  replyMessage: replyMessage ?? _replyMessage,
);
  String? get replyID => _replyID;
  String? get repliedBy => _repliedBy;
  String? get replyMessage => _replyMessage;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final map = <String, dynamic>{};
    map['ReplyID'] = _replyID;
    map['RepliedBy'] = _repliedBy;
    map['ReplyMessage'] = _replyMessage;
    return map;
  }

}
```

And here is the JSON response from the API. (with one entry)

```
{
    "CourseLessonDetailsData": [
        {
            "request_status": "Successful",
            "DiscussionDetails": [
                {
                    "DiscussionsMessages": [
                        {
                            "MessageID": "301",
                            "ID": "48",
                            "StudentName": "Person Name",
                            "Message": "This is from Message",
                            "ReplyMessage": "This is a Reply Message",
                            "OtherStudentMessages": [
                                {
                                    "ReplyID":"939",
                                    "RepliedBy":"Reply Person",
                                    "ReplyMessage":"resubmit means you can submit again if you want until the deadline is over"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: The problem is instead of adding data to a list after your api call, you are returning the whole model. So, when you want to reload more data, your previous data is lost.

Comment: @Md.KamrulAmin this where I need help. How to?

Answer (score 0):

I edited your code but could not test it out, please check it if it works.
You need to make a list variable that will hold all your paginated data. Then call your future and then after result is not null, add it to your list and change your loading status to false. After, use scrolls and scrollListener reaches max extent, change offset and call your api again and after result is not null, again add to your list.

```
class PaginatedScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const PaginatedScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PaginatedScreen> createState() => _PaginatedScreenState();
}

class _PaginatedScreenState extends State<PaginatedScreen> {

  final scrollController = ScrollController();
  int offSetCurrent = 0;
  bool hasMore = true;
  bool isLoading = true;
  List<PaginatedModel> listOfData = <PaginatedModel>[];

  @override
  void initState() async {
    super.initState();
    
    var result = await getDiscussion(offSetCurrent);
    if (result != null) {
      setState(() {
        listOfData.add(result);
        isLoading = false;
      });
    }
    
    
    scrollController.addListener(() async {
      if (scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent == scrollController.offset) {
        offSetCurrent = offSetCurrent + 10;
        setState(() {
          isLoading = true;
        });
        var result = await getDiscussion(offSetCurrent);
        setState(() {
          listOfData.add(result!);
          isLoading = false;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose(){
    scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<PaginatedModel?> getDiscussion(offSetCurrent) async {
    // if (isLoading) return;
    // isLoading = true;

    SharedPreferences sp = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var parameters = {
      'RangeFrom':offSetCurrent.toString(),
      'AccessToken':sp.getString('AccessToken'),
      'DiscussionID':'22848',
    };
    var urlfetch = Uri(
      scheme: "https",
      host: baseUrl,
      path: discussionAPIPath,
      queryParameters: parameters,
    );
    try {
      http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(urlfetch.toString()));
      var data = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
      var snapshot = PaginatedModel.fromJson(data);
      var itemsTotal = snapshot.courseLessonDetailsData!.first.discussionDetails!.first.discussionsMessages!.length;
      if (itemsTotal < 10){
        setState((){
          hasMore = false;
        });
      }
      print(data);
      print('Discussion API HIT with offset $offSetCurrent');
      // isLoading = false;

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {

        return PaginatedModel.fromJson(data);
      }
      else {
        print(response.statusCode);
        return null;
      }
    }
    catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      rethrow;
      // return null;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: isLoading 
          ? CircularProgressIndicator() 
          : ListView.builder(
        itemCount: listOfData.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          //do your widget building here
          // do whatever you did in your future builder here
          return Text(listOfData[index].courseLessonDetailsData![0].requestStatus!);
        },
      ),
      // body: FutureBuilder(
      //     future: getDiscussion(offSetCurrent),
      //     builder: (dCtx, dSnapshot){
      //       if (dSnapshot.hasData){
      //         var itemCount = dSnapshot.data!.courseLessonDetailsData!.first.discussionDetails!.first.discussionsMessages!.length;
      //         return ListView.builder(
      //             controller: scrollController,
      //             shrinkWrap: true,
      //             itemCount: itemCount + 1,
      //             itemBuilder: (context, idx){
      //               if (idx < itemCount){
      //                 return Column(
      //                     children: List<Widget>.generate(dSnapshot.data!.courseLessonDetailsData!.first.discussionDetails!.length, (i) => Container(
      //                       margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      //                       child: Column(
      //                         children: [
      //                           Html(data: dSnapshot.data!.courseLessonDetailsData!.first.discussionDetails!.first.discussionsMessages![idx].message.toString()),
      //                         ],
      //                       ),
      //                     ))
      //                 );
      //               }
      //               else {
      //                 return Padding(
      //                   padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 32),
      //                   child: Center(
      //                     child: hasMore? CircularProgressIndicator() : Text('No More Data'),
      //                   ),
      //                 );
      //               }
      //             }
      //         );
      //       }
      //       else {
      //         return const Center(
      //           child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      //         );
      //       }
      //     }
      // ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The following error happened: _PaginatedScreenState.initState() returned a Future.

State.initState() must be a void method without an `async` keyword.